# Не работают условия JS, почему и как решить?

Tags: javascript, jquery, веб-программирование

В JS после первого условия далее условия даже в других функциях, даже с другими `id` и классами, не работают (именно на скролл).

Расскажите, почему так и как это пофиксить? У меня для каждого текстового поля своя протяженность менюшки и для каждого блока свои `id` и классы. И после первого условия для 1ого текстового блока, далее все функции принимают значения этого условия, и почему-то игнорируют свои же условия. Ниже привожу пример. 1ое условие до 3500 пикселей скролл. Второе условие до 3000 игнорируется и берется 3500 с первого условия.

```js
$(window).on("scroll", function() {
  if (($(window).scrollTop() > 900) && ($(window).scrollTop() < 3500)) {
    $("#tabid").addClass("tab1");
    $("#London").addClass("tabedit");
  } else {
    $("#tabid").removeClass("tab1");
    $("#London").removeClass("tabedit");
  }
});

$(window).on("scroll", function() {
  if (($(window).scrollTop() > 900) && ($(window).scrollTop() < 3000)) {
    $("#tabid").addClass("tab2");
    $("#Paris").addClass("tabedit2");
  } else {
    $("#tabid").removeClass("tab2");
    $("#Paris").removeClass("tabedit2");
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$("#tabid").` - выбирает один и тот же элемент (один) в обоих условиях.

А условие во втором обработчике включает в себя условие из первого.

Comment: Как сделать так, чтобы условия не включались в друг друга?

Comment: @BlackerAndrew Прочитайте Ваш вопрос. Вы не пишете, какое поведение является Вашей целью, а только говорите: "Вот код, как починить?"

Comment: Да, всё верно. Как починить то, что условия не выполняются, только 1) И задал доп.вопрос по этому выше.

Comment: @BlackerAndrew "все функции принимают значения этого условия" - смысл этой фразы от меня ускользает.

Comment: Имелось в виду, что проверяется только 1 условие, в остальных функциях условия не соответствуют значениям, которые я в них указывал (в данном случае 3000 px.).

Comment: @BlackerAndrew Русский - Ваш родной язык? Условия не могут "соответствовать значениям". Условия существуют *независимо* от значений. Что у Вас чему не соответствует - по-прежнему покрыто мраком. Но Вы пытайтесь. Успехов Вам и хорошего настроения.